# Saving the contents of a TextArea to a file

Tags: java, file, javafx

Can this method be modified to be more efficient?

```
public void saveFile(File file, TextArea textArea) {
    if (file != null) {
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            writer.write(textArea.getText());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("savefile exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Some suggestion:

1. A "save to file" method without a valid file is useless. If the file is `null` your method is a no-op without a warning for the user.
2. Code reuse: your code works with TextArea only. A better solution would be a String argument instead of TextArea.
3. Method name: "saveFile" is too generic
4. Exception handling: you should catch the exception only if you know how to handle it or if you enrich the exception with new information before rethrow it

My version:

```
public void writeStringToFile(File file, String text) throws IOException {
    if (file == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file cannot be null");

    if (text == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("text cannot be null");

    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        writer.write(text);
    }
}
```

But... **DON'T REINVENT THE WHEEL!**

A better solution is the Apache [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class, see `writeStringToFile` method.

ps: English is not my mother tongue

Comment: Don't buy a new wheel when you already have one: what about Files.write in the various signatures? Still, best answer so far (+1)

Comment: I'll implement your suggestions....

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you go roundabout to create buffered writer, as `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));` would suffice. In case of exception, it would make more sense to write to `System.err` stream as opposed to `System.out`. Also, depending on the context, I would rethrow exception, and catch in place where I am calling this method, so e.g. if I call `saveFile` method inside `save` method, I can show a message box saying save failed inside catch clause.

Comment: Au contraire: Files.newBufferedWriter should be the *normal* method today to create a buffered writer, that's why it has been added to the base library in Java 7. Please take this from the discussion to your own book of recipies.

Comment: Don't talk nonsense, both of these are equally normal to use. When you have a File already, using FileWriter makes a code more readable. 

I should share a page about not making sarcastic remarks from my recipe book one day.

Comment: I think it always depends on the approach the programmer is taking. Newbie here, all comments are helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

To get the `Path` use [`File.toPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath()) instead of getting the absolute path as a string and passing it to the Path constructor.

As opposed to @coderino I like the use of `Files.newBufferedWriter`. It makes the code clearer. However you should specify the charset, otherwise the file may not be portable between systems as by default it uses the system default charset which depends on locale.

Answer (score 2):

This is the modified method based on the suggestion given with the additional charset for user convenience. If this is still modifiable to be more efficient, please be patient, I'm a newbie.

```
public void writeToFile(File file, String text, Charset charset) throws IOException {

    if (file == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument, file cannot be null.");
    }
    if (text == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument, text cannot be null.");
    }

    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file.getPath()), charset))) {
        writer.write(text);
    }
}
```